# Docker container with random date

Tags: docker, containers, date

I was running a container based on the image `linuxserver/radarr:3.0.0.3095-ls12`.
Once I updated the tag/version to `linuxserver/radarr:3.0.0.3807-ls24` the application stopped working.

After debugging a little I noticed that `date` behaves weirdly in this image:

```
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint "" linuxserver/radarr:3.0.0.3807-ls24 date
Fri 20 Feb 1970 03:17:15 AM UTC
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint "" linuxserver/radarr:3.0.0.3807-ls24 date
Sun 01 Mar 1970 09:09:15 AM UTC
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint "" linuxserver/radarr:3.0.0.3807-ls24 date
Thu 19 Feb 1970 09:04:59 AM UTC
```

But the old doesn't

```
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint "" linuxserver/radarr:3.0.0.3095-ls12 date
Sat 10 Oct 2020 12:15:09 AM UTC
```

After meditating for a while, assuming some kind of weird dark magic in the clock, decided to run it with `--privileged` for full/raw access

```
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint "" --privileged linuxserver/radarr:3.0.0.3807-ls24 date
Sat 10 Oct 2020 12:16:22 AM UTC
```

And it worked well (and so did the app, but not important to the question).

I have gone through `docker history` of both images but a lot of `COPY` and `RUN curl` that might have different results between builds. Still, I don't think anyone (image maintainers) would want to mangle with the date, so it must be something out of their control (no `libfaketime` found)...

This is a multi-arch image and these results are from a raspberry Pi (so the arm build of the image). In my amd64 linux laptop, the latest image reports proper `date` even without privileged...

What could it be? How can I even start to debug this as I cannot use the `--privileged` flag?

Comment: Same thing happened to me with that container and also after updating linuxserver/jellyfin image.
The problem only happens with ARM (raspberry pi 4B in my case).
I tried changing the date with all known methods to no success. Finally, I found a blog post on linuxserver blog addressing the issue.
They offer a set of solutions. I haven't tested them yet, but I'm sure they will work.
https://docs.linuxserver.io/faq#my-host-is-incompatible-with-images-based-on-ubuntu-focal

Comment: Didn’t you put this up as answer? I was going to accept it once I tried it (haven’t had the chance yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on [Adrian](https://serverfault.com/users/607385/adrian)'s comment (which should have been an answer):

According the [linuxserver FAQ](https://docs.linuxserver.io/faq#my-host-is-incompatible-with-images-based-on-ubuntu-focal) this is a [known issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40734) with docker and ubuntu focal images since March 2020.

It seems it is related to outdated libseccomp (the only dependency from Docker besides kernel itself) which explains why a `privileged` container was not affected (syscall filtering disabled).

They list possible resolution steps.
In my case (as OP), I'm using Buster, so installing an up to date libseccomp from buster-backports solved the issue

```sh
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 04EE7237B7D453EC 648ACFD622F3D138
 echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install -t buster-backports libseccomp2
```

Comment: You are my hero! Worked!